# Blazor Wasm Multiple Openid Providers

Tags: c#, authentication, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I am working with multiple authentication providers like Google and Microsoft and I need to implement a login with both Google and Microsoft with two buttons in the UI. I have previously logged into Google and Microsoft on separate projects and it worked, but I need both in the same project in a wasm-only project. Both buttons should perform its action using only blazor wasm (no server involved). Here is my code:

```
using BlazorOidcAD;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

public class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
        builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com/";
            options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "mygoogleclientId";
            options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "token id_token";
            options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("openid");
            options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("profile");
            options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("email");
            options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = "my call back url";
            options.ProviderOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "postlogouturl";


        });

      builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "microsoftauthority";
            options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "my microsoft client id";
       


        });



        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```